# How to know web app framework by looking at the source code

Tags: web, frameworks

I am more towards to infrastructure but want to learn web app.

I have been given access to Windows server + IIS, how do I know what web framework or even just what language of this web app? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

install "Wappalyzer" browser extension
The extension automatically checks pages you visit and reveals the technologies the website is built with.